# How to evaluate this complex integral on this particular contour?

Tags: complex-analysis, exponential-function, complex-integration

So I'm integrating

$$I = \int_C e^z dz$$ where C is defined as the curve along $Re(z)=1$ and $Im(z)=0$ to $\pi$.

I know that $e^z$ is analytic, but I don't think any of the integral theorems I know work on this since I don't think it's a closed contour (it's basically a line, right?)

Anyway, I tried parametrizing it as $z=e^{\iota\theta}$, and we get $dz = \iota e^{\iota\theta}d\theta$, so that we're integrating $e^{e^{\iota\theta}}$.

I have two questions essentially;

1. Am I doing this right?
2. What limits do I use? $0$ to $\pi$? Since the $1$ is constant? Or something else? I think this contour goes from $z=1$ to $z = \iota\pi$, so I'm guessing that the limits should be what I mentioned, but I'm not completely sure.

Can someone help explain please?

Comment: Better terminology would be that $C$ is the _curve_ (not "area")... and maybe "along $\Re(z)=1$, from $\Im(z)=0$ to $\Im(z)=\pi$."

Comment: Ohh wait yeah, sorry. Edited, and will keep this in mind, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\exp'=\exp$ and your path goes form $1$ to $1+\pi i$,$$\int_Ce^z\,\mathrm dz=e^{1+\pi i}-e^1=-e-e=-2e.$$

Comment: Oh. Interesting. So there's no need to complicate this? Also, this is just normal integration, isn't it? I usually can't tell when you can just integrate a complex integral simply tbh, but thanks for this!

Comment: Since your function has a known antiderivative, why to look for something else?

Comment: Ahh yepp, okay, makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Wait, isn't the answer $-2e$? Since it'd be $-e - e = -2e$?

Comment: Yes. My bad. I've edited my answer.